# Date time format string C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have problem to format string for correct date time parsing.
I need to get variable of type "DateTime" from string.

For example, date is presented as a string "13-08-21/11:14:11".
Correct date and time is: 13 of August 2021, time 11:14:11 AM.

Here is code that I use:

```
DateTime dateTime;
string strTime = "13-08-21/11:14:11";
string strFormat = @"dd-MM-YY'/'HH:mm:ss";

dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strTime, strFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I get error: System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
I try with different formating options but no results.

Can please someone help me to properly write format string?
Thank you.

Comment: It's `yy` (lowercase), not `YY`.

Comment: I try with lowercase but still same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format is a bit wrong.

```
DateTime dateTime;

string strFormat = @"dd-MM-y/HH:mm:ss";

//string strTime = "13-08-21/11:14:11"; // for date requested
string strTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(strFormat);  // for troubleshooting
Console.WriteLine("\nstrTime is: " + strTime);
dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strTime, strFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If the above is not working, I would try troubleshooting.  Rather than getting a datetime from a string, I would use your formatting string to convert Datetime.Now into a string.  Then that string should be able to be converted back to a datetime with the formatting string.

If your ouput looks like:
strTime is: 20-09-YY/10:32:43
then it is probably the year segment that is wrong.

Here is more about the formatting:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: Hello Mr. Lord. Thanks for your answer but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @IvanRistic why don't you try turning DateTime.Now into a string.  If a part is missing from that string, that is what you need to focus on.  Both Andrew and my post work on my computer.

Comment: I just tested new string variable with value of DateTime.Now.ToString() and try to parse back to DateTime with proposed formatting string and get same error!

Comment: @IvanRistic, okay, what is the string that it prints out to console?

Comment: I found that new string from DateTime.Now have one dash between date and time ("13-08-21-11:14:11") instead of slash.

Comment: I changed formating to be like this: @"dd-MM-y'/'HH:mm:ss" and now it parse properly but when I use my string then shows again error.

Comment: This mean that my original string is "wrong". I get it from data table from database. When I debug this I see normal date time (like I wrote in question). I don't know how to check this string?

Comment: I use Debug.WriteLine() because it is a WinForm application. In output window I get this: strTime is: 20-09-21/17:48:56 It looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question.

The first problem was a wrong format string.

And then there was an empty space at the end of my input string which I did not see at the beginning.
Because of that parsing was not possible.
Solution is to trim the end of string and now parsing works properly.

Thank you for help Mr. Lord and Mr. Morton.